# Returning first line from a string

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have string which contains three lines how i can retreive first line from the string in sqlserver.

forex:

```
declare @Str as nvarchar(200)

Set @Str='This is for test'+char(10)+
         ' second line'+char(10)+
         'Third line'

insert into some test table.
```

how i can retrive the first line from this.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str,0,CHARINDEX(char(10),@Str))
```

EDIT: If you have also text with only one line you can use a CASE:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(char(10),@Str)=0 THEN @Str
   ELSE SUBSTRING(@Str,0,CHARINDEX(char(10),@Str)) END
```

Comment: some cases the string might be having only one line inthat case it wont return any string?

Comment: @Nag Added a select for that case

Answer (score 3):

At least since Postgres 9.0:

```
SELECT split_part(some_column, E'\n', 1) from some_table
```

note: `E` is required to escape the literal to a [line break](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Note_Sets.cNoteCode,
    SUBSTRING(Note_Sets.cScript,1,CHARINDEX(char(10),Note_Sets.cScript)) as cFirstLine
from dbo.Note_Sets
```

Can either use char(10) or char(13).